# Drag and drop a window upwards in sikuli

Tags: sikuli

**Background:**
I am trying to automate a desktop application using sikuli with Java.
When we click on a Browse button in the application, it will open a new window to select destination folder to download some files.
We need to click OK button once the folder is selected.

**Problem:**
Whenever we click on Browse button, an enlarged window is opened by default in the lab execution machine where the script is running.
Due to this, the OK button is not visible on screen.
We have to move the Browse window upwards in order to make it visible.

I tried using Region.dragDrop() method to move the window upwards.
However, it is not find the destination match which is behind the Browse window.

Please guide me in coming up with a working approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect solution to your problem. Since drag/drop and other "visual" actions are usually more flaky and harder to automate, I suggest you use keyboard shortcuts as much as possible. In your case, if the blocking window is opened last, I assume it becomes the active window which means you can minimize it using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> combination (assuming you are in Windows).